# Plotting a function defined by a sum

Tags: plotting

I need to plot the following sum, but I don´t know if I have a mistake in the code,

[image]

[image]

Comment: So we should retype it? That's kind of you.

Comment: did you realise none of your function arguments actually appear in the function.  If that sum converges the plot will just be a constant.

Comment: Please post your actual Mathematica code, not an image of it. Without real code no one will be able to work with it to see what you might have done wrong, nor will they be able to experiment with possible repairs.

Comment: You have mistakes. Your function definition makes no sense. `Plot` does not plot lists returned by `Table` (look at `ListPlot`). There may be others.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = (-200 (-1)^n + 200)/(n Pi Sinh[n Pi])*Sinh[n Pi/2]*Sin[n Pi/2] // 
  Simplify[#, Element[n, Integers] && n > 0] &

(*  -((100*(-1 + (-1)^n)*Sech[(n*Pi)/2]*
         Sin[(n*Pi)/2])/(n*Pi))  *)
```

If you use [`Regularization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Regularization.html) the `Sum` is a constant `25`

```
Sum[expr, {n, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> #] & /@
 {"Abel", "Borel", "Cesaro", "Dirichlet", "Euler"}

(*  {25, 25, 25, 25, 25}  *)
```

Using [`NSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSum.html)

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 200},
 NSum[expr, {n, 1, Infinity},
  Method -> "AlternatingSigns",
  WorkingPrecision -> 30]]
```

[image]